# Get certain value from json

Tags: javascript, json

How can i get value of `geoplugin_continentCode` JSON.stringify or what is the best way to get data

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('//www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
       alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
     //  alert((JSON.stringify(geoplugin_continentCode));
       //geoplugin_continentCode
    });

    $.getJSON('//ip-api.com/json?callback=?', function(data) {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
      // alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jrm2pk7q/1/

Comment: `console.log(data["geoplugin_continentCode"]);` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `console.log(data.geoplugin_continentCode);`?

Comment: working demo of the above suggestions: http://jsfiddle.net/jrm2pk7q/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('//www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
      console.log(data.geoplugin_continentCode);
    });
});
```

Comment: It gives error in production Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=jQuery164028891548834075054_1536751670632&_=1536751670960”.

Answer (score 1):

After parsing to Json ...

```
var dt = JSON.parse(data);
alert(data.geoplugin_continentCode);
```